# How to add background color and set opacity in Jumbotron using inline CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a Jumbotron that has a background image with white text.  To make the text more readable, I'm tring to set the text background to black and set the opacity to 0.5.  Not sure where I'm going wrong here:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: #336699;
     !important;background-image: url(http://www.apptivsolutions.com/portals/2/Images/mainbanner.jpg);
     background-size: cover;">

    <h1>
    <span style="color:#ffffff;",background-color:#000000;,
           opacity:0.5;>SmartTapp
    </span>
    </h1>
    <p>
    <span style="color:#ffffff;",background-color:#000000;,opacity:0.5;>
     Integrated Marketing for the Craft Brewing Industry.
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using with opacity at the end like :  `background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5)`

Comment: it is problem in style syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect inline style css syntax error

```html
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: #336699 !important; background-image: url(http://www.apptivsolutions.com/portals/2/Images/mainbanner.jpg);background-size: cover;">
        <h1>
        <span style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#000000;opacity:0.5;">SmartTapp
        </span>
        </h1>
        <p>
        <span style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#000000;opacity:0.5;">
         Integrated Marketing for the Craft Brewing Industry.
       </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  That worked perfectly!  Cheers! - I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: It's always a good idea to point out the problematic syntax rather than simply fixing it for them.

Comment: @WildBeard why you are give down vote? it is already add the question title

Comment: You solved the problem but you are pretty vague about what the problem was. You corrected the syntax but never explained what was wrong or where.